# tweaking python strawpoll bot

Tags: python, bots

I found this bot on [Github](https://github.com/MoonfireSeco/strawpoll-bot) but it seems outdated, the code breaks at the following lines:

```
# Get Checkbox ID
ind = page.find ("\"field-options-")
checkboxID = page [ind:]
checkboxID = checkboxID [checkboxID.find ("value=\"") + len ("value=\""):]
checkboxID = checkboxID [:checkboxID.find ("\"")]
checkboxID = str (int (checkboxID) + opt - 1)
```

with this error message:
**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

and here is the poll page code:

```
<div class="block">
 <div class="field is-poll-answer">
  <label class="b-radio radio">
   <input type="radio" name="poll_answer" value="rzgrdf2fh2sb"> 
    <span class="check"></span> 
    <span class="control-label">A</span>
  </label>
 </div> 
 <div class="field is-poll-answer">
  <label class="b-radio radio">
  <input type="radio" name="poll_answer" value="gd1br74f8xhx">
   <span class="check"></span>
   <span class="control-label">B</span>
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but you might wanna take a look at https://github.com/sendQueue/Strawpoll-Bot .

a working solution to find checkbox values is:

```
def find_checkbox(content, op):
    option = content[content.find("options"):]
    option = option[option.find("value=\"") + len("value=\""):]
    option = option[:option.find("\"")]
    return int(option) + op - 1
```

content is the html source and op the checkbox counting from 1..n